# Parsing ISO 8583:1993 with j8583

Tags: java, iso8583, iso8583-1993, j8583

I am using [j8583](http://j8583.sourceforge.net/xmlconf.html) Java library to generate and read `ISO 8583:1987` messages and it is working perfect.

Now I want to generate and read `ISO 8583:1993` messages. Can I do it with making some tweaks in the same code or do I need to use some new library to achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked ate the source code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
No I did not look in the J8583 source code. 
I posted this question because before start  of the development I want to understand that same version  j8583 (1.10.2)  support 1993 functionality or not, if anybody have any experience on the same please share.

Comment: Good luck with that :-)

Comment: I trying with same version let see if I face some issue or not  but I am confuse with the expiation in this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583  
I will keep posted with  my findings.
Thanks

Comment: Till that time if anybody have any example or experience with ISO 8583 -1993 version please share with me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve the same making some changes in your creating and parsing guide for your ISO Messages. As messages of `ISO 8583:1987` version starts with `0xxx` and messages of `ISO 8583:1993 version` starts with `1xxx`.

For example,

While working with **`ISO 8583:1987`** you create message with `<template type="0200">` as below:

```
<template type="0200">
    <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="6">650000</field>
    <field num="32" type="LLVAR">456</field>
    <field num="35" type="LLVAR">4591700012340000=</field>
    <field num="43" type="ALPHA" length="40">Fixed-width data</field>
    <field num="48" type="LLLVAR">Life, the Universe, and Everything|42</field>
    <field num="49" type="ALPHA" length="3">840</field>
    <field num="60" type="LLLVAR">B456PRO1+000</field>
    <field num="61" type="LLLVAR">This field can have a value up to 999 characters long.</field>
    <field num="100" type="LLVAR">999</field>
    <field num="102" type="LLVAR">ABCD</field>
</template>
```

And when you are working with **`ISO 8583:1993`** you have to create message with `<template type="1200">` as below:

```
<template type="1200">
    <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="6">650000</field>
    <field num="32" type="LLVAR">456</field>
    <field num="35" type="LLVAR">4591700012340000=</field>
    <field num="43" type="ALPHA" length="40">Fixed-width data</field>
    <field num="48" type="LLLVAR">Life, the Universe, and Everything|42</field>
    <field num="49" type="ALPHA" length="3">840</field>
    <field num="60" type="LLLVAR">B456PRO1+000</field>
    <field num="61" type="LLLVAR">This field can have a value up to 999 characters long.</field>
    <field num="100" type="LLVAR">999</field>
    <field num="102" type="LLVAR">ABCD</field>
</template>
```

Similarly, while parsing the **`ISO 8583:1993`** you have to change the `<parse type="0210">` to `<parse type="1210">` as below:

```
<parse type="1210">
    <field num="3" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
    <field num="4" type="AMOUNT" />
    <field num="7" type="DATE10" />
    <field num="11" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
    <field num="12" type="TIME" />
    <field num="13" type="DATE4" />
    <field num="15" type="DATE4" />
    <field num="17" type="DATE_EXP" />
    <field num="32" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="35" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="37" type="NUMERIC" length="12" />
    <field num="38" type="NUMERIC" length="6" />
    <field num="39" type="NUMERIC" length="2" />
    <field num="41" type="ALPHA" length="16" />
    <field num="43" type="ALPHA" length="40" />
    <field num="48" type="LLLVAR" />
    <field num="49" type="ALPHA" length="3" />
    <field num="60" type="LLLVAR" />
    <field num="61" type="LLLVAR" />
    <field num="70" type="ALPHA" length="3" />
    <field num="100" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="102" type="LLVAR" />
    <field num="126" type="LLLVAR" />
</parse>
```

Comment: Thanks For the Response Arpit . 
I did the same thing and working fine with my code.